# How to draw a "list of" relation between 2 objects?

Tags: oop, object, uml

I am drawing a schema to represent the relation among my objects... For instance, the following schema shows that an object `A` is a pair of an object `B` and an object `C`.

Now I want to represent an object `D`, which is a list of `A`, I just don't know how to draw the arrow between `A` and `D`...

Could anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a 1 to N relation, write a line from D to A with an aggregation or composition symbol (open/closed diamond symbol).

Write at the A side * (meaning 0..n) or 1..n if there needs to be at least one element in the list.

See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/nov03/t_modelinguml_db.pdf for an example, search for the Flight and Plane class diagram about halfway the document.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your model is not correct. If you say that `A` is a pair of `B` and `C` then the aggregation should start at `A` and finishes at `B` and `C`. The drawing you show says that `B` contains `A` and `C` contains `A`. 
As for showing multiplicity, add `[0..*]` to the end closer to the class that has multiple instances. If `D` has a list of `A`, add an aggregation/composition link from `D` to `A` and set the multiplicity as said above. But note that this does not specify that `D` contains a list of `A`, only that `D` has many (0 or more) instances of `A`. If you want to specify that the reference is implemented as a list, you can add a `{list}` constraint on top of the link or don't use the link and add an attribute to `D` using `alist:A[0..*] {list}`.

See [this](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-reference.html) site for more information